# Python efficient obfuscation of string

Tags: python, string, unicode

I need to obfuscate lines of Unicode text to slow down those who may want to extract them. Ideally this would be done with a built in Python module or a small add-on library; the string length will be the same or less than the original; and the "unobfuscation" be as fast as possible.

I have tried various character swaps and XOR routines, but they are slow. Base64 and hex encoding increase the size considerably. To date the most efficient method I've found is compressing with zlib at the lowest setting (1). Is there a better way?

Comment: Use a good, proven, widely-used encryption scheme. Everything else is broken as soon as anyone competent gets an idea of what you're doing. Yes, it will take some time, but that's the price you *have* to pay if you want anything remotely decent. If the data isn't even important enough for that, just save yourself the hassle and send it as plain text.

Comment: You said "slow down", not "prevent".  Are you really trying to prevent people from reading the text?  Under what conditions does the original text need to be read?

Comment: Speed is more important to me than security. Encryption slows the access of the data significantly. If there was an encryption scheme that did not cause a significant bottleneck, a lot of developer's issues would be solved. Is there not room for a middle ground with this issue? Sure, someone with the knowledge and some spare time could get the data, but is it worth their effort.

Comment: This issue is similar to the quality of locks on ones home. A bank vault door would be the most secure, but how many have that? Most realize it is nearly impossible to keep a determined intruder out, but they still have relatively weak locks on their doors to keep the less determined out. That is all I want with this obfuscation. I just don't want to leave the doors to my house wide open.

Comment: @Tim: "quality of locks" reasnoning is faulty.  Software is not the same as a crowbar for opening a mechanical lock.  Once the algorithm is known the "slow down" effect immediately drops to zero.  Bank vaults with known combinations are as useless as screen doors with simple hooks to keep the closed in the wind.  Same with this "obfuscation".  Once the obfuscation is known, the slow-down drops immediately to zero.

Comment: Yes, it drops to near zero when the intruder knows algorithm and how to implement it, but that takes effort. Really, the only difference between simple obfuscation and military grade encryption is the effort one or many want to put forth to break it. However, to the casual observer using a text editor, one looks as garbled as the other. I venture most will not take the time to mess with it.

Comment: @S.Lott, if the idea is to hide text that the program decrypts for itself, any skilled programmer who wants to make the effort can crack it no matter what algorithm you use, because the program includes all the needed information. I gather Tim simply wants to stop people who will just look at the code with a hex dump program.

Comment: @Tom Zych: "the program includes all the needed information".  Except, of course, the run-time-supplied key that's used.  Lacking that key passphrase makes the encryption more difficult to break.

Comment: @S.Lott: Did anyone say the key would not be incorporated into the program? I got the impression this would be self-contained.

Comment: @Tom Zych: "self-contained" and using a pass-phrase at startup are common.  SSL, for example, works that way inside Apache.  Hardly a limitation.

Comment: @Tom: You are correct. I just want the text to be scrambled for the average user so they can't easily copy/paste, extract, etc. and "borrow" the data. Speed is most crucial. I have over 31,000 lines of text in an sqlite DB and true encryption slows searching down to a crawl. zlib compression is much better but still considerably slower than plain text.

Comment: @Tim: "true encryption slows searching down to a crawl"?  Why?  You only encrypt as part of downloading.  Why encrypt what's in the database?

Comment: @S.Lott: Because the DB is distributed with the app and can be easily opened with an SQLite Viewer (Firefox). Sqlite encryption (APSW) is also very slow. zlib is the fastest method I have found. Short of making a plain text index (which would be accessible via a viewer as well), I haven't found a better way.

Comment: @Tim: How big is this DB?  Is it over 1GB?  If not, why is it a relational database and not pickled Python structures that you decrypt once when you load them into memory?  Why mess with a (slow) RDBMS that's distributed with an app?

Answer (score 19):

How about the old [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) trick?

Python 3:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> x = 'some string'
>>> y = codecs.encode(x, 'rot13')
>>> y
'fbzr fgevat'
>>> codecs.decode(y, 'rot13')
u'some string'
```

Python 2:

```
>>> x = 'some string'
>>> y = x.encode('rot13')
>>> y
'fbzr fgevat'
>>> y.decode('rot13')
u'some string'
```

For a unicode string:

```
>>> x = u'國碼'
>>> print x
國碼
>>> y = x.encode('unicode-escape').encode('rot13')
>>> print y
\h570o\h78op
>>> print y.decode('rot13').decode('unicode-escape')
國碼
```

Comment: Updated for unicode - just escape it first. The escaping adds no overhead for non-unicode characters.

Comment: Didn't know about the unicode-escape, nice. However, it takes roughly twice as long as zlib.compress(s, 1). One would think a simple substitution would be faster, but not according to my quick tests.

Comment: One note is that `rot13` only transforms the 26 letters of the English alphabet. Numbers and punctuation will not be obfuscated.

Answer (score 13):

This uses a simple, fast encryption scheme on `bytes` objects.

```
# For Python 3 - strings are Unicode, print is a function

def obfuscate(byt):
    # Use same function in both directions.  Input and output are bytes
    # objects.
    mask = b'keyword'
    lmask = len(mask)
    return bytes(c ^ mask[i % lmask] for i, c in enumerate(byt))

def test(s):
    data = obfuscate(s.encode())
    print(len(s), len(data), data)
    newdata = obfuscate(data).decode()
    print(newdata == s)


simple_string = 'Just plain ASCII'
unicode_string = ('sensei = \N{HIRAGANA LETTER SE}\N{HIRAGANA LETTER N}'
                  '\N{HIRAGANA LETTER SE}\N{HIRAGANA LETTER I}')

test(simple_string)
test(unicode_string)
```

Python 2 version:

```
# For Python 2

mask = 'keyword'
nmask = [ord(c) for c in mask]
lmask = len(mask)

def obfuscate(s):
    # Use same function in both directions.  Input and output are
    # Python 2 strings, ASCII only.
    return ''.join([chr(ord(c) ^ nmask[i % lmask])
                    for i, c in enumerate(s)])

def test(s):
    data = obfuscate(s.encode('utf-8'))
    print len(s), len(data), repr(data)
    newdata = obfuscate(data).decode('utf-8')
    print newdata == s


simple_string = u'Just plain ASCII'
unicode_string = (u'sensei = \N{HIRAGANA LETTER SE}\N{HIRAGANA LETTER N}'
                  '\N{HIRAGANA LETTER SE}\N{HIRAGANA LETTER I}')

test(simple_string)
test(unicode_string)
```

Comment: Looks good, but I didn't mention I am limited to Python 2.5-2.7. I don't even have 3.x on my system to test with. What is the 2.x equivalent to the bytes module?

Comment: @Tim: Try this. I only have 2.6 on this machine and it looks like it didn't interpret the `\N{...}` stuff, so I couldn't test it as completely as I'd like to.

Comment: Thanks for the 2.x version. Unfortunately, it is much slower than zlib.compress(). For a 6MB file this takes about 5.1 sec. With zlib it takes .18 sec. About 25 times faster.

Comment: Probably the difference between C code and native Python code. Go with zlib, then.

Comment: One should also be carefull when dealing with the obfuscated string, since it may have \x00 (string terminator character) in it. In my case, it was truncating a obfuscated password when stored in the database.

Comment: @TomZych Thanks for your code. I am using it to obfuscate sqlite rows. It is hunderesd of thousands  1k fields. It is now a bottleneck. Slowest part of the code. How we can make it faster ?

Answer (score 4):

use codecs with hex encoding , like :

```
>>> codecs.encode(b'test/jimmy', 'hex')
b'746573742f6a696d6d79'
>>> codecs.decode(b'746573742f6a696d6d79', 'hex')
b'test/jimmy'
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your input, if it's over 1K then using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) is about 60x faster (runs in less than 2% of the naïve Python code).

```
import time
import numpy as np

mask = b'We are the knights who say "Ni"!'
mask_length = len(mask)

def mask_python(val: bytes) -> bytes:
    return bytes(c ^ mask[i % mask_length] for i, c in enumerate(val))

def mask_numpy(val: bytes) -> bytes:
    arr = np.frombuffer(val, dtype=np.int8)
    length = len(value)
    np_mask = np.tile(np.frombuffer(mask, dtype=np.int8), round(length/mask_length+0.5))[:length]
    masked = arr ^ np_mask
    return masked.tobytes()


value = b'0123456789'
for i in range(9):
    start_py = time.perf_counter()
    masked_py = mask_python(value)
    end_py = time.perf_counter()

    start_np = time.perf_counter()
    masked_np = mask_numpy(value)
    end_np = time.perf_counter()

    assert masked_py == masked_np
    print(f"{i+1} {len(value)} {end_py-start_py} {end_np-start_np}")
    value = value * 10
```

[image: Table of results]

**Note:** I'm a novice with `numpy`, if anyone has any comments on my code I would be very happy to hear about it in comments.